# Research masters programs in theoretical computer science (with a focus on complexity theory)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, research-practice

I am in my **2nd year** of my Computer Science degree. I am deeply interested in **Complexity Theory**, and I plan to pursue a career in this field

I am from South Asia, and research here is not up to par, especially in TCS

I am looking for some quality research masters programs, as I feel a direct jump to PhD in a foreign country is probably not the best decision for me. However, **I do plan to pursue a PhD degree eventually** in this field and continue in academia

I am only aware of *TU Wien's Logic and Computation* program and *MPRI* in Paris. I am looking for other programs as well, particularly ones with **sufficient funding** and with a **strong focus on complexity theory**

Comment: Closely related question where you may find some valuable advice: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53490/129

Comment: Speaking as an MPRI student: MPRI is *not* focused on complexity theory. There is an absolutely excellent (and quite difficult) course on parameterized complexity, but quite strongly focused on more algorithmic aspects (e.g., designing FPT algorithms with treewidth). There is one course called “randomized complexity” which is mislabeled and will probably be renamed. That's about all. The breadth of other subjects taught is pretty varied, from graph stuff and combinatorics to symbolic dynamics, WQOs, verification, proof assistants, type systems, semantics, ...

Comment: Also, remember that the European education system works differently than in the US and other parts of the world. You can't jump to PhD directly. The organization is 3 years of bachelor degree + 2 years of master's degree, then PhD.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this link useful [https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~smattw/masters/masters.html](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Esmattw/masters/masters.html)

(I would have commented, but my reputation is too low)